# Spliting a VERY long table in multiples pages html/php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

here is the problem. I have no right to create a database and I receive a csv that countain MASSIVE amount of data each day. (More than 200 000 rows)

Data that I must make accessible for everybody on the intranet. So I created a simple html/php page that extract all the rows and display those informations in a table with a filter on every column with a simple fgetcsv.

Problem is that the web browser is not suited to display that much informations at the same time so it makes it crash or freeze for a while, and you can't do anything for a while.

I wanted to know if anyone knew a way to say to the page "load only the first 100 rows for exemple, then automatically create a next page that will load and display the next 100 rows etc."

I manages to DISPLAY only the first x rows and then when you clicked a button the table would expand with the next x rows, but they are still all loaded at once. The y remaining are just hidden, so the browser still dies or freeze.

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: It would be useful if you could show some code of what you have done so far. Are you just rendering all the rows and put a "display:none" on it?

Comment: You want a JavaScript-based solution that will [load a CSV file via AJAX](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/1632/import-csv-into-datatable) -- problem is, that's still going to download the entire CSV document at once, which will use up memory. The best solution really is to use a database instead, which can be told to LIMIT the number of rows returned.

Comment: You can just retrieve the rows you need even if you are using a csv, there is no need to have a database. It's exactly the same problem he has to solve even if he uses a database.

Comment: To Alexander : To display only x rows of the whole file I used a jquery plugin that I use as a filter, but that also has a function to display x amount of data. But since it stills loads all the file i only use the plugin to filter the columns.

Answer (score 2):

It's a generic pagination question really. It doesn't matter if your data is stored in database or in a CSV file.

Just pass some offset argument to your PHP script via query string or URL rewriting and use it to select only part of your CSV list.

Like this: `/big-table.php?page=3`.

```
// Getting passed argument.
$pageNumber = (int) $_GET['page'];

// Items per page default.
$itemsPerPage = 100;

// Calculating offset.
$offset = ($pageNumber - 1) * $itemsPerPage;
```

Then use the `$offset` and `$itemsPerPage` to retrieve only part of your CSV file by limiting scope of your CSV parsing loop.

You can also pass items per page value as an argument to your script in order to control this value from your web interface. For example, if you want to create a dropdown menu with ability to select 10, 50, 100 items per page, etc.

And if you want it - you could always use AJAX to fetch more items dynamically, it doesn't really affect your pagination implementation server-side, only an output format (JSON instead of HTML).

Of course database implementation will work faster and I would recommend to opt for it instead if possible. And/Or you can use some caching layer to speed things up.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the jquery Datatables plugin http://datatables.net/

It's quite simple to do what you want using that.

Refer to either this example: http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html or http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

Comment: Thanks, but problem is that your plugin still loads the entire file. It just "hides" a part of the content and show it on demand. But you still load the 200k rows of the csv which takes too much memory and make you browser crash

Answer (score 0):

The most sensible thing is to demand database access. Right now, you're told to build a car but without using wheels and an engine.

Right now, you could use PHP to split the big csv in multiple smaller files of *n* rows long. You have to do this only once, or once a day/hour if the big csv is updated. Then you load each of these files only when you need them, either by navigating to another page or dynamically using Javascript.